# Some Questions About Chess

Tags: combinatorics, algorithms, game-theory, artificial-intelligence

I have to questions about the chess game: please help me to understand it.

1- How can a computer program know if this move or that move is better? It calculates all possbile continuation and examine? But if it does, how did it knows waht is the best continuation?

2- What is the estimate of the possible best continuatuons after every move? Is there a pattern, a sequence for it?

Comment: Some more research effort would have been nice.

Comment: The Chess programming wiki may help you. For example the [Alpha-Beta algorithm](http://chessprogramming.wikispaces.com/Alpha-Beta). Some level are examined only. Every position has a value (with ponderations for the different pieces).

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_chess has some discussion of your first question.

Answer (score 1):

For question 1
The basics of computer player chess is it has value (coin weightage point) for each chess items and in the same way it has value(move weightage point)  for each possible move for on chess item.
With this it will decide which the best move is.
For example if the opponent’s queen and pan are possible to cut-down in your next move the program suggest to cut-down the queen (coin weightage point for queen is  higher than pan)

For question 2
It is not such simple to explain! Need deep knowledge about subject and programming concepts (follow some google links!).

Answer (score 0):

For the first question, there is a nice article by John Geanakoplos that discusses various heuristics used by chess computers:

[When Seeing Further is Not Seeing Better](http://cowles.econ.yale.edu/~gean/art/p0797.pdf) (with L. Gray), (1991), Bulletin of the Santa Fe Institute, 6(2): 1-6.

Naturally, the paper is probably not giving you the state of the art though.